# Keep Apple Mail offline but still send emails

Tags: macos, osx-lion, apple-mail

When processing tons of pending emails I like to put Mail (OS X Lion) in offline mode so that I do not receive more emails and therefore distraction.

The problem is that I am not able to send email in this mode, or is it possible somehow?

Answer (score 3):

If you don't want to receive mails automatically, simply go to Mail's preferences and disable automatic downloads.

Set *Check for new messages* to *Manually* and hit the envelope symbol in the toolbar (or press ⇧⌘N) to fetch new mail.

[image]

If you want to switch this mode globally, you can create a new Automator service that runs the following shell script (drag *Run Shell Script* from the left to the right pane):

```
pt=$(defaults read com.apple.mail PollTime)
if [ $pt == 0 ]; then
  defaults write com.apple.mail PollTime 1
else
  defaults write com.apple.mail PollTime 0
fi
```

The service should look something like this:

[image]

Of course you can change the `PollTime 1` to another value, as long as it's available from the select dropdown (i.e. `23` will not work). Save the service and then under *System Preferences » Keyboard » Keyboard Shortcuts*, add a new global shortcut for your service.

Comment: ups! I did not realize about it! Last thing is, can one assign a global shortcut for switching this from manual to automatic and viceversa?

Comment: As usual, you can set the preferences through an Automator service—see my updated answer.